# Grails select: equivalent of optionValue to value

Tags: grails, one-to-many

In grails select you have an optionValue attribute.

What is the equivalent of it into value?

For example this is the normal `value="${inventoryInstance?.inventoryItem*.id}"`

then i have `optionValue= stockItemDescription` , this also works without the `value`

this `stockItemDescription` is from the `inventoryItem`

what do i change in the `value="${inventoryInstance?.inventoryItem*.id}"`

so that instead of the id displayed it will display the `stockItemDescription`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As inferred from the question inventoryInstance hasMany InventoryItem. I think you are looking for this:

```
<g:select from="${inventoryInstance?.inventoryItem.toList()}" optionKey="id" value="stockItemDescription" value="${inventoryInstance?.inventoryItem.first().id}"/>
```

Hope this Helps!!!